# How to reduce the font of the text in the legend box printed in the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-size, legend

I am trying to plot around 10 plots in a single figure. I also could put the legend box separately.  But, I am unable to reduce the size of the font in the legend box.  Can anybody suggest me the procedure to reduce the font size in the lengend box.

I am herewith giving the instructions that I have used: But it is not getting affected in the end result.

```
# Shink current axis's height by 10% on the bottom
  box = ax.get_position()
  ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.90, box.height])

  # Put a legend to the right of the current axis
  ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), numpoints = 1)
  #plt.show()

  fontP = FontProperties()
  fontP.set_size ('x-small')

  filename1 = "DelayCellSpur"+ str(measuredFrequencyUnderTest)+"MHz.pdf"
  print filename1
  plt.savefig(filename1, dpi = None, facecolor = 'w', orientation = 'portrait',bbox_inches = None)
```

As I am a new user, I am not able to upload the image. Pls help me in reducing the size of the font in the legend box.
Thankyou,
Gopi

Comment: Language/platform? What is this?

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply..This is in python language.

Comment: Please tag it in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're using matplotlb, aren't you?

Something like this may help:

```
legend_font_props = FontProperties()
legend_font_props.set_size('small')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), numpoints=1, prop=legend_font_props)
```

See http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your answer, it is giving an answer "legend_font_props is not defined".  Can you pls help me here.

Comment: As you can see, I create a variable `legend_font_props` right here in the first line: `legend_font_props = FontProperties()`. Also, I made a typo (`setSize`) which I'll fix now.

Comment: That works, thanks! Note that `FontProperties` is in fact `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` - took me a bit to track that down.